# Special array from list of items in current dir

Tags: bash, array

I want to extract a specially formatted array from the list of current dir.

```
$ ls
Output:
fileABC.ext1
filePQR.ext2
dirMNO
dirFGH
```

I want only the dir and files of specific extension

I want an array like this
`(1 dirFGH "is a dir" 2 dirMNO "is a dir" 3 fileABC.ext1 "is an ext1 file")`

I am doing the same with

```
num=0
while read -r line
do
    if [ -d $line ]
    then
        num=$(( $num + 1 ))
        array+=(num)
        array+=($line)
        array+=("Is a dir")
    elif #check for extension used
    then
        num=$(( $num + 1 ))
        array+=(num)
        array+=($line)
        array+=("Is an ext1 file")
    fi
done < <(ls -1 --group-directories-first "$path")
```

but this method is slower. Please suggest me a same functioning but optimised method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to parse `ls`. Remember to double-quote each time you use your variables such as `"$line"`, otherwise it will be subject to splitting on `$IFS` (typically whitespace) and globbing. (As an example, if `$line` was `hello world` then your `array+=($line)` would add two values, `hello` and `world`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
array=()

for item in *
do
    if [[ -d "$item" ]]
    then
        # Directory
        array+=( $((${#array[@]} /3 +1)) "$item" 'is a dir' )

    elif [[ -f "$item" ]] && [[ "$item" = *.ext1 ]]
    then
        # Files with an ext1 suffix
        array+=( $((${#array[@]} /3 +1)) "$item" 'is an ext1 file' )
    fi
done

# Dump the array
printf "%2d. '%s' %s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

Output

```
1. 'dirFGH' is a dir
2. 'dirMNO' is a dir
3. 'fileABC.ext1' is an ext1 file
```

The expression `$((${#array[@]} /3 +1))` calculates the entry number based on the number of triple values already the array, and means that we don't need to carry `$num`.

Possible improvements

If you're looking for files of a particular type you can check them with `file`. For example, `file x.ods` on my PC returns `x.ods: OpenDocument Spreadsheet`.

You might find it easier to use two different arrays, one for the file names and one for the custom file type message:

```
filenames+=("$item")
filetypes+=('Is a dir')
```

Here the index value (`$num`) can then be derived directly by the index of the item and you don't need to store it in its own array.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Also, as you suggested to separate them, I need it this way only

Comment: do this appends all the directories first in the array??

Comment: @decipher, `*` should just sort by name, without regard for files vs. dirs. If you want dirs first, you could list them in a separate array from the files, and the concatenate the two. something like `if [ -d "$item ]; then dirs+=(...); else files+=(...); fi; all=("${dirs[@]}" "${files[@]}")`

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
array=() n=0
for f ( $dir/*(N-/) ) array+=( $((++n)) $f:t 'is a dir' )
for f ( $dir/*.ext1(N^-/) ) array+=( $((++n)) $f:t 'is a ext1 non-directory file' )
```

Note that in `zsh`, like in csh/tcsh, `$path` is the special array tied to `$PATH` (the standard environment variable that specifies the list of directories where to search for commands in) and mustn't be used as a normal variable, hence `$dir` used instead above.